# Create Refund on square_connect Ruby sdk gives INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: square, square-connect

I am using square_connect ruby gem to refund payments.

```
body =
#<SquareConnect::CreateRefundRequest
 @amount_money=#<SquareConnect::Money @amount=200, @currency="USD">,
 @idempotency_key="be70cc12-28dd-4168-96ea-6eb78f299207",
 @tender_id="asdkasdkakdakdakda">
```

All other parameters are just as intended. I have changed Tender key too.

```
result = api_instance.create_refund(authorization, location_id, transaction_id, body)
```

This gives me INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

```
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/BP6GXQNEANA9B/transactions/b2fd4689-af1b-40a4-b706-aafd592e1111/refund response_code=500 return_code=ok total_time=1.883598

SquareConnect::ApiError: Internal Server Error - {"errors":[{"category":"API_ERROR","code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","detail":"An internal error has occurred, and the API was unable to service your request."}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a major bug in the Square Connect API. I was actually trying with a wrong transaction ID, instead of getting something like "Incorrect Transaction ID" I was getting 500 Internal Server Error.

I have been using Stripe, Payflow. Authorize.net, Braintree and Moneris API for almost 2 years now but I have never received a 500 Internal server error for a wrong transaction Id. So Square needs to address it on urgent basis.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `tender_id` matches a tender you want to refund? 500 isn't the correct response, but it seems like you are likely not selecting a correct tender to refund.

Also you should look into upgrading your SDK to the latest version.